# How to store a terraform plan output file on Azure storage?

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

As per the official documentation :

*You can use `terraform plan` with the optional `-out=FILE` option to save the generated plan to a file on disk, which you can later execute by passing the file to terraform apply as an extra argument. This two-step workflow is primarily intended for when running Terraform in automation.*

From what I understand, when running Terraform using Azure DevOps, this output file is saved in the running directory on the agent machine. I'm wondering if Terraform supports saving this file in an Azure storage for later review similar to where we store the state file. If terraform doesn't support that what other ways do we have to save this file in Azure Storage.

Thanks in advance.

Note : I run the `terraform plan` command using an AzureCLI task in a Classic Release pipeline.

Comment: You could follow up the plan step which outputs the plan with an Azure CLI command which copies it to Azure Storage.

Comment: @MarkoE could you please elaborate? thanks

Comment: You can think like that like store the plan file in a seperate folder and you can do automation using powerautomate whatever new file will upload in that local folder that should be uploaded in blob container. : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/upload-files-to-azure-blob-storage-using-power-automate-desktop/ba-p/2316960

Comment: You can also use the Az COPY,Powershell to copy the file to Azure Blob Storage : https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/azure-cvo-blg-how-to-upload-files-to-azure-blob-storage

Comment: In yaml pipelines, one option is to save the tfplan as a build artifact from plan stage and consume it in apply stage. But the tfplan is basically a zip file that contains plan, state file, and tfconfig. So, storing the tfplan in a secure location (something like azure storage) is necessary as this can contain sensitive information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on some comments provided, here is a solution that works :

Add an AzureCLI task after the Terraform Plan task and use the below command

`azcopy copy '<SourceFilePath>' "https://<StorageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/<ContainerName>/<TargetFileName>?<ContainerSASToken>`

Comment: It hurts to know that Terraform doesn't provide an option natively to store the Plan Output to an Azure Storage similar to how the State file is stored.